# Azure Dev Ops - Pipeline - YML file condition statement not working on Build Configuration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run Nuget Pack only when it is Release build configuration. Our pipeline has a strategy of running the same thing for Debug and Release.

I put in a condition to do the Nuget Pack only on Release but for both Debug and Release it is skipping the step with this message "Skipping step due to condition evaluation."  I have tried several different things in the eq() and I can't get it to work.

Here is the YML task. For some reason, it is not picking up Release.
**Bottom line** - I want it to run this task on Release builds but skip it on Debug builds.

```
 strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix:
      AnyCPU-Debug:
        buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
        buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
      AnyCPU-Release:
        buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
.
.
.
- task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: Pack nuget package
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Configuration'], 'Release')
    inputs:
      command: custom
      arguments: 'pack Garnet.nuspec -OutputDirectory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Properties -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg -version $(Build.BuildNumber) -Verbosity Detailed'
```

I have also tried this and it it doesn't recognize Release:

```
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: Pack nuget package
    condition: eq('$(buildConfiguration)', 'Release')
    inputs:
      command: custom
      arguments: 'pack Garnet.nuspec -OutputDirectory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Properties -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg -version $(Build.BuildNumber) -Verbosity Detailed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include `succeeded()` in your condition, and you need to make sure the variable is defined at compile time, not runtime. You are using a compile time variable, so this should be fine.

Here is a working example snippet:

```
strategy:
  maxParallel: 2
  matrix:
    AnyCPU-Debug:
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
    AnyCPU-Release:
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Always Run"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "I will always run"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Only Debug"
  condition: and (succeeded(), eq(variables.buildConfiguration, 'Debug'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Debug!"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Only Release"
  condition: and (succeeded(), eq(variables.buildConfiguration, 'Release'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Release!"
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: 'Build.Configuration' (and $(buildConfiguration)) is just a built in ADO variable

Comment: Are you sure? I do not see it listed in the documentation as a pre-defined variable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: No luck with trying the and(succeeded()...
Ok ... At the top of the YML we have:
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix:
      AnyCPU-Debug:
        buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
        buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
      AnyCPU-Release:
        buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'

I tried:
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Configuration'], 'Release'))

also tried:
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('$(buildConfiguration)', 'Release'))

Bottom line - how would you set up a condition on a task that only runs on Release build?

Comment: I updated the main post to show this info.

Comment: The $(buildConfiguration) value is used in other tasks and showing as "Release" so I know it is being set right.

Comment: Yes!!!! You got it working with that answer.  The key was   eq(variables.buildConfiguration ...     Thanks everyone for your quick responses!